# what is the way to change the mouseover combobox Background using xaml only in windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

As Style triggers are not supported in Windows 8 so what is the way to change the mouseover combobox Background using xaml. i know the way of altering the template and style of combobox but i know that is not the right way to do..

Comment: There's nothing wrong with altering the template...or even creating your own if it suits your purpose.

Comment: look if i want to use 2 or 3 styles for combobox..then i have to make 2-3 templates in which most of the xaml is same..that's i don't want..

Comment: Have you find any solution to this problem? I want to not hide the Border of the ComboBox when I hover over it... is that a way to accomplish this?